# Pausar video youtube al ocultar div con scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo programado un contenedor fullwidth que contiene un video de youtube.
Necesito que cuando se haga scroll el div se oculte y el vídeo pare de reproducirse. He conseguido ocultar el div al hacer scroll pero no consigo pausar el video.

Ahora mismo tengo el siguiente código:

```js
// EFECTOS SCROLL START:
    var lastScrollTop = 20;
    var section = $('#start');
    var container = $(".center_content_start");
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            section.addClass('fuera');
        } else {}
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });


    $(document).click(function () {
        section.addClass('fuera');
    });

    $(".h1_start_content ").click(function (event) {
        section.removeClass('fuera');
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```css
#start {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: @blanco;
    z-index: 9999999999;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.center_content_start {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1920px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.h1_start_content {
//    flex: 0 1 45%;
//    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

/*video youtube*/
.video-container {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
/*fin video youtube*/

.img_start_content {
    flex: 0 1 30%;
    //    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.h1_start_content .span_start a {
    color: @negro;
    font-family: @akrobat !important;
    font-size: 7vw;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.phrase_separator {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

.phrase_separator:hover span {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.phrase_separator:hover p {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#span_1 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    z-index: 999999;
    opacity: 0;
}

#div_1:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    ransition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#div_2:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    ransition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#div_3:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    ransition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#div_4:hover span {
    opacity: 1;
    ransition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.fuera {
    top: -5000px !important;
    transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<section id="start" class="ocultar">
        <div class="center_content_start">
            <div class="h1_start_content slideInLeft animated margin_element video-container">
              <iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"width="100%" height="443" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eYsYQr0U14U?autoplay=0&fs=1&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&rel=0&cc_load_policy=0&start=0&end=0&origin=https://youtubeembedcode.com"></iframe>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
```

Con este código consigo que el video se oculte al hacer scroll, pero no consigo pausarlo al ocultarlo, ya que es una molestia que el video continue sonando cuando no lo estás viendo.

He encontrado esta web: http://jsfiddle.net/ZcMkt/
donde se pausa un vídeo al hacer click, es algo parecido a lo que quiero hacer, pero como he dicho anteriormente lo necesito hacer cuando hago scroll.

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? ahora mismo estoy intentando el siguiente código, pero no responde:

```js
    // EFECTOS SCROLL START:
    var lastScrollTop = 20;
    var section = $('#start');
    var container = $(".center_content_start");
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    var div = document.getElementById("popupVid");
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (st > lastScrollTop) {
            section.addClass('fuera');
    var iframe = div.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow;
    func = event == 'hide' ? 'pauseVideo' : 'playVideo';
    iframe.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + func + '","args":""}','*');
        } else {}
        lastScrollTop = st;
    });
```

```html
            <div id="popupVid" class="h1_start_content slideInLeft animated margin_element video-container">
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"width="100%" height="443" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eYsYQr0U14U?autoplay=0&fs=1&iv_load_policy=3&showinfo=0&rel=0&cc_load_policy=0&start=0&end=0&origin=https://youtubeembedcode.com"></iframe>
            </div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que mires esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164942/stop-embedded-youtube-iframe

Comment: Hola @YasielHernández he intentado adaptar el código que me has enviado al mío propio, pero no ha dado resultado, el video no hace caso al js, o no lo estoy haciendo correctamente:    https://ibb.co/deJ2AJ  Te adjunto la imagen del código. Tambien le he puesto la clase myVideoClass al iframe.

Comment: Prueba la siguiente validación https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668636/check-with-jquery-if-div-has-overflowing-elements